# WebSocket server, connection forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I'm working on a C# WebSocket server (currently supported by https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17).
The server is working with the Socket object of the .NET for the server to listen and for each client to send and receive messages.

I built a web client that connect to the server, It can connect successfully and i can send messages between clients.

Everything is working great!

Now, if i'm connecting to the server and leave the client for a while without sending messages, the server throwing an exception that says:

> Int32 Send(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags):An
> existing  connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The exception, as you can see is from the Send method of the client socket in the server, this is looks very wired because i didn't sent any data from the client and no one sending data to this client back so how can it be that the Send method can throw an exception and why this exception is thrown?

Comment: Can you post the send code (in particular, the line that threw the exception)?

Comment: ...also, are you aware the WebSockets will be supported directly in .Net4.5?

Comment: yeah i'm aware with the WebSocket in .Net 4.5 but i don't know when it will be published.

Comment: and the line that throws the exception is:
this.clientSocket.Send(sendData.ToArray());

another are thrown from:
this.clientSocket.EndReceive(_result);

as i said, i didn't sending any data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a timeout!

WebSockets are just a wrapper around TCP/IP raw sockets ([Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaf5t5kz.aspx) class in .NET) - which timeout if nothing is sent, and nothing is keeping the connection alive.

AFAIK currently the WebSocket API isn't very well defined as far as how to keep the connection alive. I was experiencing the same and had to just switch over to using a ping (empty message) to keep the connection alive (I'm using the Microsoft sockets implementation).

If you're [reinventing the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) for a non final spec, just remember that you'll have to keep reinventing it every time the spec changes. I specifically chose to use  the Microsoft sockets preview so that when it's released I'm pretty much not going to have to change any code. I don't run in IIS - I run as a console app and it's working mostly great so far but I have very very few users.

Note: The problem i was having that led me to find this question was if I send 10 messages without receiving a reply then the connection is closed. I'm still looking into why this is - whether its a bug / feature of WebSockets or a feature of the Socket class. it's possible I'm hitting a 65kb limit but my messages are small and I don't think that's why. Just be aware of this when testing whatever you're working on becasue it gives the same error you got.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have exclude the usage of different protocols between the servers and the clients (silly assumption, but you never know).
If your code reaches the Send method without a prior Receive from the client, then it's obvious that something is wrong with the server code. Use trace and/or log to get more information even for abc's like entering wait to receive, receiving, received, exiting receiving etc.

Comment: "If your code reaches the Send method without a prior Receive from the client, then it's obvious that something is wrong with the server code". I'm already know that... and the log that i did leads me to the error message that i received....

Comment: You may extend your logging for abc's like above.

Comment: There is a great change for having the error in front of you but you can't see it. It happens to all. If you log every single step of the execution flow you increase your chances to locate it. Log (as info) that your entered the waiting to receive in line x, receiving in line x+2, exit receiving in line x+4 etc... It may look silly but most of the times is successful.